# Passing variables via the URL in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have been over the examples and for some reason this isn't working for me, its a very simple thing

the url I need to access is

```
/event-details/3
```

or some other number and no matter what I do to the routeParam items I can't get it to work.

here is my config for it .

now I am not doing anything with it yet, just trying to get the page to come up and right now its coming up blank or not forwarding at all

```
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/event-details/:item_ID', {
        controller: 'edController',
        templateUrl: 'com/modules/Events/events-detail/views/event-details.html',
        hideMenus: true,
        protectedArea: true,
        title: 'Event Details',
        menuGroup: 'Events',
        description: 'This is the event details screen',
        keywords: 'keyword',
        breadcrumbList: [{view: '/',title:'Home'},{view: '/events-main', title: 'Events Main'},{view: '/event-details', title: 'Event Details '}]
  });
}])
```

Based on the examples I have seen my format is correct but it doesn't seem to want to work,

any ideas ?

Comment: are you using `html5Mode`? and what server are you using, and what do the server routes look like?  the folks that created ui-router, which is a replacement for the angular router, write a pretty in depth [FAQ](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode) on this issue that you may want to read through.

Comment: any error in the console ?

Answer (score 2):

Pass vairable via URL redirect eg:http://localhost/doctor?test=1

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.home.html',
})

export class HomeComponant {
title = 'Home';
constructor(
    private router: Router,

) {}

onSubmit() {
  this.router.navigate(['/doctor'],{queryParams:{test:1}});
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While it is best to always follow a common convention, I am finding that when I inherited a specific Angular/Node application that it is NOT like apps I have built or other ones that I had seen.

Example of URL routing:

***Module:***

```
.when('/outage/notes/:group?:groupid?', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/outagenotes.html'
```

***Controller:***

```
.controller('OutageNotesController',

function ($http, $scope, $routeParams, Categories, Tip, $location, error, $sce) {
     //.....
     var group = $routeParams.group || 1;
     $scope.groupid = $routeParams.groupid;


      $scope.detailFrame = "http://URL/" + group + "?groupid=" + $scope.groupid);
```

***URL:***

```
http://localhost:1337/other/#/outage/notes/10297?groupid=4
```

You should see how the URL relates to the routing with the module and the controller above

Comment: Tom, Thank you I ended up changing my when statement to when('/event-details/:itemID?', and that worked perfectly passing the value like this /event-details?itemID=3, solved it perfectly.

Comment: Glad to hear.   I really don't like inheriting someone else's application which to me I don't like the when statement not being standard that I am use to ,  and that templateUrl  ... it generates the exact file in the public/partials/  folder  and it is not like it is even combining any other information the way this previous developer set things up.   2.0 is going to be interesting with Angular since I recall that controllers are "going away"